# How to erase the thin side line right bottom?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, mask, cgpath

I want compound view's shape from Oval shape subtract Rect shape,

so first I create a mask image:

```
    let paths = CGMutablePath()
    //Oval shape path at left
    let leftPath = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 150), transform: nil)

    //Rect shape path at right
    let rightPath = CGPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 120, height: 100), cornerWidth: 8, cornerHeight: 8, transform: nil)

    paths.addPath(leftPath)
    paths.addPath(rightPath)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 220, height: 200))
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    ctx?.addPath(paths)
    ctx?.clip(using: .evenOdd)

    ctx?.addPath(leftPath.cgPath)
    ctx?.clip(using: .evenOdd)

    ctx?.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    ctx?.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 200))

    //the mask image
    let maskImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

next I use this image for mask:

```
    let maskView = UIImageView(image: maskImage)
    maskView.contentMode = .center    
    imageView.mask = maskView
```

run App, I get this:

[image]

looks good?not really...

if you look carefully,you will notice a thin line at view right bottom

It's not OK for me!

How do I erase the sideline??? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the ellipse, then clear the rounded rect.

```
import UIKit

let ellipse = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 150), transform: nil)
let roundedRect = CGPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 120, height: 100), cornerWidth: 8, cornerHeight: 8, transform: nil)

let maskImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 220, height: 200)).image { rendererContext in
    let ctx = rendererContext.cgContext

    ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    ctx.addPath(ellipse)
    ctx.fillPath()

    ctx.setBlendMode(.clear)
    ctx.addPath(roundedRect)
    ctx.fillPath()
}
```

Result:

[image: playground output]